# Developing a Mail.app plug-in under OS X Lion: where to begin?

Tags: objective-c, macos, email, plugins, osx-lion

I'm in the mood for developing a custom plug-in for Apple's default OS X mail client under OS X Lion (10.7). I can find a lot of plug-ins for older versions of Mail.app online, and some background information on the (officially unsupported and undocumented) plug-in architecture used by these old versions of Mail, but not for the newest version.

I know there are plug-ins for Lion's mail app so I know it's possible to do this, but I'm having a hard time finding out how to begin. Xcode offers templates for Address Book, Quartz Composer and Installer plug-ins, but not for Mail plug-ins.

I specifically do not want to work exclusively with AppleScripts because they won't allow me to do what I want to do: customize the application's interface, views and toolbars and such.

I am an experienced Objective-C developer and have built several apps for iOS, so the language and Xcode will pose no problems.

I think I just need to know 1) where/how to begin and 2) how to find reliable information about Mail.app's plug-in architecture. Can anybody point me in the direction of documentation, example projects or tutorials for developing such plug-ins? Of course, any other remarks, hints and tips are very welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is at least one plugin for Mail.app which works on Lion. It's Growl Mail, plugin to connect Mail.app to Growl. Growl Mail has sources available on [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/growlmail/), so, in my opinion, it's good point for start.

Oh, I almost forgot about second plugin, which I use, [TruePreview](http://christianserving.org/project/truepreview). It has also sources [available](http://christianserving.org/websvn/listing.php?repname=TruePreview) in internet.

Answer (score 0):

I found these resources to be helpful.

- http://www.tikouka.net/mailapp/ - repository of Mail plugins, at least some of which are open source so they can serve as examples (most support Mountain Lion).
- http://www.hawkwings.net/ - Tips and add-ons for Apple Mail